# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (61, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am working in keras tensorflow backend on Windows 10.
I am not able to interpret the  meaning of the error

## Here is a snippet of my code

```python
{
model = Sequential([
    #Dense(32, input_shape=(1080,1920,2)),
    Dense(32, input_shape=(250,250, 3)),
    #Dense(32, input_shape=(3,1080,1920,2)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
    Dropout(0.02),
])

layer = Dropout(0.02)

#further layers:
model.add(Dense(units=3)) #hidden layer 1
model.add(Dense(units=1)) #output layer
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=None,padding='valid', data_format=None))

model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer='sgd')

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)


test_generator = ImageDataGenerator()

validation_generator = test_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'human_faces/validation',
    target_size=(250,250),
    batch_size=3,
    class_mode=None,classes=0)


model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=1,## batch_size,
    #steps_per_epoch=3,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    #  validation_steps=61 )  # batch_size)
    validation_steps=1)

}
```

## My error:

> File "C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/untitled1/work.py", line 89, in
>   
>       validation_steps=1) ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with
>   shape (61, 1)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the shapes of the output of your network (which is the output of the `MaxPooling2D` layer) and the output you seem to expect (based on the desired "true" output example you feed together with each input to `model.fit_generator()`.

To investigate the mismatch you have to examine your (unshown) code of `train_generator` to see what output shape you are expecting, and can use `model.summary()` to see the conflicting output shape generated by the `MaxPooling2D` layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following argument to Cov2D:

`padding='SAME'`

Like:

`model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3),padding='SAME'))`